# I have used Javascript reader.onload = function(e) in apex code and it's not working

Tags: javascript, apex

I have tried to pass the uploaded files value to `apex` method but facing some issues in `javascript` logic.

I have added alert after `reader.onload = function(e)` but didn't get any alert when I'm hitting this javascript function.

[HTML CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jGl4.png)

```
function SponsorshipLetter() {
  var files = document.getElementById('fileUpload');
  var appId = getCookie('apex__app');
  var fileName = 'Passport';
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.file = files[0];
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    alert('Hello 1' + document.getElementById('fileUpload').value);
    var att = new sforce.SObject("Attachment");
    att = fileName;

    att.ContentType = this.file.type;
    var binary = "";
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
    var length = bytes.byteLength;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
    }

    att.Body = (new sforce.Base64Binary(binary)).toString();
    alert('attt');
    PAP_Finances.sponsorFileUpload(att.Name, att.Body, att.ContentType, appId,
                                   function(result, event) {
      return 'Success';
    });
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}
```

Comment: Do you see any error message in the console of your browser, like `ReferenceError: e is not defined`, `TypeError: e.target is undefined` or any other error?

Comment: I am getting this error only.  `Uncaught ReferenceError: sponsorCreation is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (PA_Homepage:1388)`

Comment: can you kindly post the HTML snippet as well?

Comment: I have added HTML snip